# multiple errors in my website like position of body & adding 2 columns in main box

Tags: html, css

i'm making a website and i have encountered several errors in the code. any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

the errors are:

1. i want the body of the website to be in the centre of the screen, not at the top
2. i want to add two columns in the main box, but the columns aren't showing. i did add code to fix this table problem but i don't think it's working

here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LAINWEB</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Neocities, HTML, aesthetic, web 1.0, old web, 90's, 80's, early 2000's,personal website,">
  
   
    <style>
    @font-face {
     font-family: hearts;
     src: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/s/1479f8x52y3z5u4/rainyhearts.ttf') format('truetype');
 }

    @font-face {
    src: url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/7bidj4o8lc71b8u/Hantam.ttf);
    font-family: hantam;
}

 html {
     font-size: 17px;
     line-height: 14px;
     font-family: "hearts";
     padding: 5px;
     cursor: url("/images/cursors/torocursor.png"), auto;
     scrollbar-color: #f48ee6 #fad1e8;
 }

 body {
     
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     background-image: url("https://lifted.crd.co/assets/images/gallery01/a307cfec.png?v=a0ae4590");
 }

 a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #ef8a85;
 }

 a:hover {
     cursor: url("/images/cursors/torocursorpoint.png"), auto;
     color: #00b2c5;
 }

 hr {
     border-top: solid 1px;
     border-color: #b6a898;
 }

 p {
     margin: 10px;
 }

 h1 {
     font-family: hantam;
     font-size: 30px;
     color: #F9A1CC;
     line-height: 18px;
     margin: 0px;
     font-weight: normal;
     text-align: center;
 }

 .table1 {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     display: block;
     border-spacing: 0px;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     width: 812px;
 }

 .table1 td {
     vertical-align: top;
     border: none;
     padding: 0px;
     position: relative;
 }

 .table1 tr {
     vertical-align: top;
     border: none;
     padding: 0px;
     position: relative;
 }

 .headbox {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-top: 0px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     height: 80px;
     width: 800px;
     position: relative;
     padding: 10px;
 }

 .footbox {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-top: 10px;
     width: 900px;
     padding: 0px;
     height: 100px;
     text-align: center;
 }

 .titleimg {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: -20px;
     left: -15px;
     z-index: 10;
 }

 .bar1 {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     border: 3px double #B1B1B1;
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding: 5px;
     padding-bottom:50px;
     width: 170px;
     min-height: 100px;
     margin-top: 7px;
     position: relative;
 }


 .mainbox {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     border: 3px double #B1B1B1;
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding: 20px;
     width: 570px;
     height: 400px;
     margin-left: 4px;
     margin-top: 7px;
     position: relative;
     
.column {
float: left;
width: 37%;
padding: 10px;
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

}
 

 
      

      li {
        list-style: none;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }

      .hder {
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-top: 1px solid #b6a898;
        padding: 2px;
        list-style: none;
        width: 176px;
        font-family: "MS UI Gothic", Tahoma;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        color: white;
      }

      

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    


    

    <table class="table1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="bar1">
            
            

              <li><a href="/about.html" target="framebox">about</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="/reading diary.html" target="framebox">reading diary</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="/music.html" target="framebox">music</a>
              </li>
              
              </li>
            </ul>

            
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="mainbox">
          <div class="row">
  <div class="column">
</div>
   <img src="https://barbara.crd.co/assets/images/gallery34/c3f48eed_original.gif?v=078d66a6">
           <div class="column">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
            
          
</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="footbox">
    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for 1:
Add this to your body style:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

*Remove margin (optional)*